# I want to create object of inner class in C++, or may be nested class

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have outer class as A and a inner class B

```
template <class T, class K>
class A::public T::RadioSignal, public VarMethod<T> {
private:
B *bObject;
public:
class B : public std::vector<SamplePoint*>
    {
    public:
        B(A<K, T> *outerInstance);
    };
}
```

I am getting below error: Unknown type name 'B'

Comment: Thanks for down vote! May I know reason?

Comment: Move the private section after the public section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is at line `B *bObject;` ? But at that moment the `class B` is not yet defined.

Either define the inner class ahead of it, or use forward reference. (`class B;` is probably enough?)

edit: if you would use not only pointer, but also something more of B (like `B bObject;` -> `class B;` would be not sufficient, but as you are using only `B *`, it should be enough just to forward declare existence of the class B. Then again, I would try to stay away from bare pointer usage, why don't you declare the full class B first and then declare directly `B bObject;` as member instance of A? So you don't have to deal with new/delete.

Comment: My mistake! Sorry for being a noob